# Чому використовують "відділення" в назвах підрозділів установ?

Tags: граматика, орфографія, морфологія, росіянізм

Наприклад, "відділення банку\пошти". Відділення - процесс, дія за знач. відділи́ти й відділи́тися. Є слово "відділ" - наслідок, підрозділ, одна з частин чого-небудь цілого, на які воно поділяється або його поділяють за певними ознаками. Це помилка чи є пояснення?

Comment: А що пишуть словники, з якими ви звірялися перед тим, як опублікувати запитання? Чи були якісь неточності чи суперечності між ними, які ви помітили, і тому ставите це запитання?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тлумачний словник розглядає слово *відділення*, як синонім до слова *відділ*.
**ВІДДІ́ЛЕННЯ**, я, с.
2. Те саме, що ві́дділ 2, 3, 5. – Ось відділення, – санітарка розкрила перед ним двері, – дев'ята палата друга ліворуч (Є. Кононенко); Відкривались відділення банків (О. Гончар); Автоматизований цех має два незалежних відділення (з наук.-попул. літ.); Реабілітаційне відділення лікарні працювало з постійною напругою (з газ.); У першому відділенні концерту звучатиме музика у супроводі клавесина (з газ.).

**ВІ́ДДІЛ**, у, ч.
2. Частина установи, закладу, підприємства. Директор повернувся до завідувача відділу капітального будівництва (Ю. Шовкопляс); Єдине, чого запрагнув [Бузина], – це перейти у відділ професора Отави (П. Загребельний);
3. Частина приміщення, що має певне призначення.Вода ринула крізь пробоїни в трюм, у машинний відділ (О. Донченко);

**Отже, у даному випадку, вирази *відділення* банку/пошти та *відділ* банку/пошти будуть абсолютно тотожними.**